# Literature about IT security from a hardware standpoint

Tags: penetration-test, hardware, professional-education

Can you point me to any book, blog, paper, anything about IT security on **the lowest possible level (hardware)**?
I'm primary interested in the motherboard, CPU & GPU, however, if you know any good reading about network equipment (on this subject), please share.

I'm not interested in how you can hack Wi-fi with aircrack or how to make a buffer overflow script. What I'm interested is, e.g., *"This CPU instruction under these circumstances can give you access to this protected data"*. Or, something like *"When you access the motherboard like this, you can bypass the BIOS password"*.

Comment: Something more indepth than say: http://www.amazon.com/Security-Engineering-Building-Dependable-Distributed/dp/0470068523/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1315498496&sr=8-1 ?

Comment: Well, chapters 3 (Protocols) and 4 (Access Control) sound interesting but the book itself seems to be written for managers, not for IT (security) professionals.

Comment: No, it's most definitely written for technical people.

Comment: Did you read it? I got that impression by looking at table of context. I'm definitely going to buy it (40$ for over 1000 pages book), just not sure is this what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have read it. It was very in depth in some places, and it glossed over things in some places. It came across as generic enough to still be viable 5-10 years after print for the most part but still technically dense. I *think* it was designed as a textbook.

Comment: Sounds like a worthwhile answer to me, @SteveS....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Andrew "Bunnie" Huang hacked the XBox by attaching monitoring equipment to the memory bus and reverse engineering security protocols by monitoring the data on the bus. He wrote a paper and a book about it.

Huang, Andrew "Keeping Secrets in Hardware: the Microsoft XBox Case Study."(http://web.mit.edu/bunnie/www/proj/anatak/AIM-2002-008.pdf) AI Memo 2002-008

Huang, Andrew "Bunnie" Hacking the Xbox : an introduction to reverse engineering (Unlimited ed. ed.). San Francisco: No Starch Press. (2003) ISBN 9781593270292

For a discussion of Intel and AMD CPU security functions McCune et al [How Low Can You Go? Recommendations for Hardware-Supported Minimal TCB Code Execution"](http://sparrow.ece.cmu.edu/group/pub/mccune_parno_perrig_reiter_seshadri_asplos08.pdf) (2008) is essential reading.

No discussion of hardware security would be complete without discussing FPGAs. Huffmire et al ["Moats and drawbridges: An isolation primitive for reconfigurable hardware based systems"](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~sherwood/pubs/IEEESP-moats.pdf) (2007) is a great overview of the use of FPGAs in secure systems.

The challenge of building solid hardware security is illustrated in Kocher et al ["Differential Power Analysis"](http://www.cryptography.com/public/pdf/DPA.pdf) (1999). In it they describe a brillant side-channel attack based on power consumption.

On the theory side Lie et al ["Specifying and Verifying Hardware for Tamper-Resistant Software"](http://theory.stanford.edu/people/jcm/papers/lie-oakland2003.pdf) (2003) is a good discussion of adding execute only control to memory to enforce access control.

Answer (score 4):

A few thoughts off the top of my head (all googleable):

- The Windows PatchGuard attack that made use of an alternative page directory (Skywing's many papers on this subject)
- Look up split-TLB attacks
- There was a Firewire-based attack on the host a few years go

No time to google or I'd find you the references, but that should get you started.